# jQuery function to intersect arrays of identical jQuery elemnets

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to build a filter with multiple selectboxes (in my case 3 selects). So I try to find a solution to filter items by this 3 filters.

I started with the following consideration:

I save filtered results in each corresponding array, so I have afterwards 3 arrays filled with jQuery-Elements. In my screenshot I pushed these 3 arrays into one array named "arrays".

[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
var output = [];
output = arrays.filter(function(v) {
        return arrays.every(function(a) {
            return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
        });
    });
```

How can find identical jQuery elements in these 3 arrays and save them in "output"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this; all it does is add all such elements of each subarray, that are present in every array, to the output array :

```
var output =[];
arrays.forEach( arr => arr.forEach( elem => 
                        { 
                            if( arrays.every( arr2 => 
                                    arr2.indexOf( elem ) !== -1 && output.indexOf(elem) ==-1 ))
                                        output.push(elem);
                        })
              );
```